# How to change CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in a generated file at installation

Tags: installation, cmake

For backward compatibility with older pre-cmake packages I need cmake to generate a pkg-config like script `foo_config` to install with my library. The library user can then execute this script with e.g.

```
foo-config --prefix
```

to find a package prefix. Other options are `--cflags` etc. Right now I can do this by creating a file `foo-config.cmake.in` which has a substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@
#
# more scripting logic
```

and I can create my actual script using in `CMakeLists.txt` the lines

```
configure_file(bin/foo-config.cmake.in bin/foo-config)
install(FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/foo-config
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_READ 
        DESTINATION bin)
```

This works fine for installing into `/usr/local` or if the user specifies `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...` at configuration time.

However CMake also allows installation via:

```
cmake --install . --prefix=/foo/bar
```

where the `/foo/bar` path will override the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. At this time my script is already configured and the previous CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX will have already been substituted. Just installing will not replace my existing substitution for @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@. Is there a facility in CMake for doing some kind of path replacement in a file at install time that I can use so that the prefix will be set correctly in the installed file?

Comment: So change `prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@` to `prefix=$(dirname "$0")/..`?

Comment: You can execute logic during installation using `install(SCRIPT)` or `install(CODE)`. However depending on the exact logic you execute there it may mess up package generation.